# PlayFramework: Render first page sample

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm new to the play framework, and following the tutorial of play 2.0.4. I have an error when I try to render the page. In the tutorial you can see they put the list of tasks and the taskform as parameters to the `render` method, but this method only accept String parameters. How do I pass these parameters?

```
public static Result tasks() {
    return ok(
        views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm) 
    ); //render only accepts String parameters at least in play 2.0.4
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Try to write more specific question, currently your code tells us ... nothing

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about this: [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTodoList) ?

In the beginning of this tutorial file index.scala.html takes String as a parameter. Whole index.scala.html file looks like this:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {

@play20.welcome(message)
```

}

This part:`@(message: String)` is definition of parameter whitch you can pass to method index.render(someString) in controller.

Further in this tutorial content of index.scala.html change to:

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[Task])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {

<h1>@tasks.size() task(s)</h1>

<ul>
    @for(task <- tasks) {
```

....
....
....

definition of parameter for method index.render changes to: `@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[Task])` and after that you can call in controller code:

```
return ok(
views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm)
);
```

I think, that you forgot to update index.scala.html file.